# Problema con variables redeclaradas en C

Tags: c

Al compilar este código me aparece este error:

```
error: ‘paso’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

¿Alguien sabe cual podría ser el fallo?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void paso (void);
void paso;
int pasos = 65;
int main(){
    int operacion;
    scanf("%d",&operacion);
    switch(operacion){
        case 1:
            paso();
            break;
    }
}

void paso (void){
    scanf("%d",&pasos);
    printf("El nuevo valor es %d",pasos);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Alguien sabe cual podría ser el fallo?

Si. Este:

```
void paso (void); // 1
void paso;        // 2
```

La primera línea declara una función llamada `paso` que no devuelve nada y no recibe nada. La segunda función define una variable de tipo `void`, lo cuál además de estar prohibido re-define la línea inmediatamente anterior.